# ConnectionString Error on publish in web server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, connection-string

I have a project in asp.net MVC with Entity Framework and my connectionsString at web.config

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="data source=localhost;Initial Catalog=telexpo_bd;Integrated Security=SSPI;User Id=telexpo_bd;Password=hey76jdhdyU;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="telexpoEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/telexpoEF.csdl|res://*/telexpoEF.ssdl|res://*/telexpoEF.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=localhost;initial catalog=telexpo_bd;integrated security=True;user id=telexpo_bd;password=hey76jdhdyU;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

this work perfectly in my PC when I emulate via Visual Studio but when I publish my application in web server doesn't work. Give the error page built by me but I was connected my web server company and after long talks they give to me this error:

> Configuration Error
>       Description:An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
>   specific error details below and modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>       Parser Error Message: The connection name 'LocalSqlServer' was not found in the applications configuration or the connection string is
>   empty.
>       Source Error:
>       Line 255: 
>       Line 256:

So, my web.config just have 193 lines and the error in web.config is at line 259!??

I was investigate by 'LocalSqlServer', "AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" and doesn't found nothing...

After some investigation across the web I found that one which generated the `AspNetSqlMembershipProvider` and `LocalSqlServer` was the machine.config at `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config` so I was thinking at server was the same but I can't change it because I have a dedicated server.

After time and tried a lot of things...but I can't find the solution about it... they insist the problem is about connectionstring. How could be?

Can someone give some suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is because of connection string, that it cannot find the connection string value under the name 'LocalSqlServer'. Try changing the connection string that matches the server in the app.config file. If you have separate projects for web and entity then include the connection string in the web.config file of web application which will resolve.